# Magento 2 Web Setup Wizard 404

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to install a new extension via the Web Setup Wizard but the page returns a 404 code.

I've tried the following so far:

- Added a "test.php" file in the /setup/ folder to verify that we can access it, I can access "https://domain.com/setup/test.php" without issues
- Added various checkpoints in the /setup/index.php file. Adding `echo "test";die();` at any point in the file correctly returns "test" when visiting /setup/. If I add that at the end of the file (after `\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require _....` visiting /setup/ retuns 404 again.

Other solutions I've found for the issue do not seem to apply.

The website is served under the root folder (not /pub/)

Another solution I found suggests using files to store sessions instead of the database, we already do that.

Any suggestions on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have .update_error.flag in your var directory . If you have it , try to remove it and test again.

```
rm -rf var/.update_error.flag
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no ".update_error.flag" file in /var/

Comment: Have your tried this command *ln -s ../setup/ setup* , or have a look on Alan Issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159

Comment: This concerns the case where you're running the website under /pub/. We're running it under the root folder. It's not an actual 404 error, I can access other files in /setup/ as well as the actual /setup/index.php file itself just fine. The 404 is thrown by the last line in /setup/index.php.

Comment: Can you paste the *nginx.conf.sample*